# React Native FlatList load more when we get to the bottom of the list

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

How to make load more with FlatList of React Native **(Not infinite)**

#### I've done this, but unfortunately it loads as infinitely.

This is my code snippet

```js
<FlatList
    data={this.props.data}
    renderItem={({ item, separators }) => (
        <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={() => this._onPress(item)}
            onShowUnderlay={separators.highlight}
            onHideUnderlay={separators.unhighlight}
        >
            <Text> {item.title} </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    )}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
    onEndReached={this.props.handleLoadMore}
    onEndThreshold={0}
/>
```

And my handleLoadMore

```js
handleLoadMore = () => {
    console.log("test"); // <---- this line run infinitely
    fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(filters)
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {
            this.setState({
                itemData: [
                    ...this.state.itemData,
                    ...responseJson.estate_list
                ],
                itemPage: this.state.itemPage + 1
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
};
```

Comment: How do you load data in this.props.handleLoadMore() function?

Comment: @nikolay-tomitov updated my questions

Comment: @Mahdi Bashirpour, you have used wrong props of FlatList. There is no such a prop named "onEndThreshold". It should be "onEndReachedThreshold".

Comment: @sandip-lipane I used both of them, but the problem did not resolve

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is issue when loading data in FlatList and your onEndReached handler will be called when the view is re-rendered. Try setting a flag like this :

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    hasScrolled: false
  }
}
```

Then add this method :

```
onScroll = () => {
 this.setState({hasScrolled: true})
}
```

Hook it up to FlatList:

```
<FlatList
onScroll={this.onScroll}
```

Finally load only when scrolled :

```
handleLoadMore = () => {
  if(!this.state.hasScrolled){ return null; }

  //here load data from your backend

}
```

Comment: Hi @Nikolay Tomitov, there is no such a prop named "onScroll" in flatlist. How to handle onScroll in flatlist?

Comment: Hi! It inherits from ScrollView and here you can see it has onScroll : 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#props

Comment: Yes, that's what I am thinking. There must be a scrollview and flatlist within it. Need to add onScroll to scrollview. Correct?

Comment: Not exactly, FlatList itself is kind of ScrollView since it inherits props from it. You can check here :
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html
Above "props" section there is  : "Also inherits ScrollView Props, unless it is nested in another FlatList of same orientation.". And onScroll is kind of such prop.

Comment: Thanks @Nikolay Tomitov, for brief description. I have not seen that part.

Comment: Hello dear ! Where you have make hasScrolled as false ?

Comment: Hi! You can reset the flag, after you reload your data.

Comment: Such a bad API design.

Comment: ScrollView props are not working my FlatList. Are there any specific instructions to use those.

Comment: No, just add onScroll attribute to FlatList. Why are they not working?

Comment: IF my API doesn't have pagination, And I got a big array and save it in the state, How can I handle this?

Comment: You can keep in state toIndex variable pointing last index of elements that you are showing. You may increase that value when you reach bottom of the list. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    loading: true
  }
}

   <FlatList  
 onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}/>

 handleLoadMore = () => {
        if(!this.state.loading){ return null; }
        
        this.setState({
        page: this.state.page + 1,
        loading: false
        }, () => {
        this.loadProducts(); 
        });
    };

 loadProducts(catId,userkey){
          $this.setState({ 
                loading:true
            });  
    }
```