# ReactNative FlatList onEndReached calling even when not scrolling

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Im trying to implement Flatlist of Somedata which contains almost 200 elements in an array that im passing in data.
Im trying to give user the option to load the rest when they scroll only. but what happening with `onEndReached` is, it is calling even though we are not scrolling (I checked by doing console log). How can I make sure onEndReached is calling only when user scrolls.

I tried setting `onEndReachedThreshold` to the max of 5 and min of 0.01 in both the cases it is not working. Tried this too but didn't work https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14015#issuecomment-310675650.

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.properties}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  keyExtractor={item => item.mlsnum}
  renderItem={({ item }) => <Text{item.title}</Text>}
  onEndReachedThreshold={0.01}
  onEndReached={() => this.handleEndReach()}
/>


async handleEndReach() {
  this.props.fetchProperties(pageNum) //call to my redux action to fetch the data
}
```

Answer (score -1):

it's a bad implementation using async in there, you should use it in the function not in the callback. Please just use

`onEndReached={() => this.fetchProperties())`

and then for the function use

```
async fetchProperties(){
 //do your async/await here
}
```

Comment: I have changed the code as you told. I have changed in the posted question too. But still the same.

Comment: The issue is still the same

Comment: Sorry , i didn't read that you wanted to load data at the end ofd the list, you can try adding a listener to see if the user is really scrolling like in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51264976/10205629

Comment: ScrollView props are not working my FlatList. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Flatlist is based over scrollview and inherits all it's props... So... try doing it in a blank project and test it.